# Preg Replace an entire div

Tags: regex, wordpress, wpallimport

I am really trying to use preg_replace an entire div and it's contents.

I've looked around quite a bit and found some similar examples.

Being a total newbie, i would greatly appreciate your advise.

Please be aware that there are nested divs within this div, but with different classes or id.

This is what i have tried, but with no success.

`[preg_replace("/<div class="ads-wrapper">/(.+?)<\/div>s","",{title_article[1]})]`

I should also point out that this is to be used with WP All Import.

EDIT //
Sample HTML

```
 <body>
<div class="ads-wrapper">
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; " id="filexxxxxxx" data-cfptl="1" data-cfpa="69067" data-cfpw="69067"><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous" data-checked-head="true"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; height: 280px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="filled"><p></p>
<div id="aswift_2_host" style="border: medium none; height: 280px; width: 752px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; display: inline-block; overflow: visible;" tabindex="0" title="Advertisement" aria-label="Advertisement"><iframe id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:752px;height:280px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx&amp;output=html&amp;h=280&amp;slotname=7139257958&amp;adk=4289402179&amp;adf=1131929206&amp;pi=t.ma~as.7139257958&amp;w=752&amp;fwrn=4&amp;fwrnh=100&amp;lmt=1671441700&amp;rafmt=1&amp;format=752x280&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Ffilecr.com%2Fwindows%2Fadobe-indesign-2022-0002%2F%3Fid%3D937678064&amp;fwr=0&amp;fwrattr=true&amp;rpe=1&amp;resp_fmts=3&amp;wgl=1&amp;dt=1671441699033&amp;bpp=5&amp;bdt=1086&amp;idt=828&amp;shv=r20221207&amp;mjsv=m202212050101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3D65a8c8bc760cb659-229ca8d322d90053%3AT%3D1671441677%3ART%3D1671441677%3AS%3DALNI_MYstdfFdvqDMbBT89kWi_GbmnW5Fw&amp;gpic=UID%3D000008d9fc9b2725%3AT%3D1671441677%3ART%3D1671441677%3AS%3DALNI_MaA7dhdMS9LxBPtWwmg_Ho-5cQXWg&amp;prev_fmts=0x0%2C1158x280&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=536657398109&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=223145590.1671441677&amp;ga_sid=1671441700&amp;ga_hid=667781215&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=0&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=1080&amp;u_w=1920&amp;u_ah=1080&amp;u_aw=1920&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=1&amp;adx=240&amp;ady=1017&amp;biw=1587&amp;bih=1080&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=0&amp;eid=44759875%2C44759926%2C44759837%2C44777508%2C31071219%2C31071259%2C44780792&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=4107435780668556&amp;tmod=302213105&amp;nvt=1&amp;ref=https%3A%2F%2Ffilecr.com%2F%3Fs%3DAdobe&amp;eae=0&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=%2C%2C0%2C0%2C1920%2C0%2C1920%2C1080%2C1600%2C1080&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7C%7CeE%7C&amp;abl=CS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=29&amp;ifi=3&amp;uci=a!3&amp;xpc=qnZUlMsEJP&amp;p=https%3A//filecr.com&amp;dtd=1078" data-google-container-id="a!3" data-google-query-id="CMm1s8athfwCFUrdhwodNQoNmA" data-load-complete="true" width="752" height="280" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<p><br>
<script> 
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); 
</script>
</p></ins></div>
<p><script type="text/javascript">;new advadsCfpAd( 69067 );</script> </p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide sample HTML for testing and answers.

Comment: Thanks, i've added the code that i want to replace

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code tested on https://www.jdoodle.com/php-online-editor/

I am using a small HTML minifier function `vh_html_minifier` that will remove the line breaks since I am unsure if the preg replace can be done with keeping the line breaks or not.

```php
/**
 * HTML Minifier function
 *
 * @param string $code HTML string.
 * @return string
 */
function vh_html_minifier( $code ) {
    $search = array(
        // Remove whitespaces after tags.
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',
        // Remove whitespaces before tags.
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',
        // Remove multiple whitespace sequences.
        '/(\s)+/s',
        // Removes comments.
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/',
    );

    $replace = array( '>', '<', '\\1' );
    $code    = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $code );
    return $code;
}

$html = '<body>
<div class="ads-wrapper">
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; " id="filexxxxxxx" data-cfptl="1" data-cfpa="69067" data-cfpw="69067"><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous" data-checked-head="true"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; height: 280px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="filled"><p></p>
<div id="aswift_2_host" style="border: medium none; height: 280px; width: 752px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; display: inline-block; overflow: visible;" tabindex="0" title="Advertisement" aria-label="Advertisement"><iframe id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:752px;height:280px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx&amp;output=html&amp;h=280&amp;slotname=7139257958&amp;adk=4289402179&amp;adf=1131929206&amp;pi=t.ma~as.7139257958&amp;w=752&amp;fwrn=4&amp;fwrnh=100&amp;lmt=1671441700&amp;rafmt=1&amp;format=752x280&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Ffilecr.com%2Fwindows%2Fadobe-indesign-2022-0002%2F%3Fid%3D937678064&amp;fwr=0&amp;fwrattr=true&amp;rpe=1&amp;resp_fmts=3&amp;wgl=1&amp;dt=1671441699033&amp;bpp=5&amp;bdt=1086&amp;idt=828&amp;shv=r20221207&amp;mjsv=m202212050101&amp;ptt=9&amp;saldr=aa&amp;abxe=1&amp;cookie=ID%3D65a8c8bc760cb659-229ca8d322d90053%3AT%3D1671441677%3ART%3D1671441677%3AS%3DALNI_MYstdfFdvqDMbBT89kWi_GbmnW5Fw&amp;gpic=UID%3D000008d9fc9b2725%3AT%3D1671441677%3ART%3D1671441677%3AS%3DALNI_MaA7dhdMS9LxBPtWwmg_Ho-5cQXWg&amp;prev_fmts=0x0%2C1158x280&amp;nras=1&amp;correlator=536657398109&amp;frm=20&amp;pv=1&amp;ga_vid=223145590.1671441677&amp;ga_sid=1671441700&amp;ga_hid=667781215&amp;ga_fc=1&amp;u_tz=0&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_h=1080&amp;u_w=1920&amp;u_ah=1080&amp;u_aw=1920&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_sd=1&amp;adx=240&amp;ady=1017&amp;biw=1587&amp;bih=1080&amp;scr_x=0&amp;scr_y=0&amp;eid=44759875%2C44759926%2C44759837%2C44777508%2C31071219%2C31071259%2C44780792&amp;oid=2&amp;pvsid=4107435780668556&amp;tmod=302213105&amp;nvt=1&amp;ref=https%3A%2F%2Ffilecr.com%2F%3Fs%3DAdobe&amp;eae=0&amp;fc=1920&amp;brdim=%2C%2C0%2C0%2C1920%2C0%2C1920%2C1080%2C1600%2C1080&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=%7C%7CeE%7C&amp;abl=CS&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=128&amp;bc=29&amp;ifi=3&amp;uci=a!3&amp;xpc=qnZUlMsEJP&amp;p=https%3A//filecr.com&amp;dtd=1078" data-google-container-id="a!3" data-google-query-id="CMm1s8athfwCFUrdhwodNQoNmA" data-load-complete="true" width="752" height="280" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<p><br>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</p></ins></div>
<p><script type="text/javascript">;new advadsCfpAd( 69067 );</script> </p></div>
</body>';

$result = preg_replace( '#<div class="ads-wrapper">(.*?)</div>#', ' ', vh_html_minifier( $html ) );

echo '<pre>' . $result . '</pre>';
```